# Vagrantで複数のVagrantfileから複数のVMを起動したい

Tags: vagrant

下記のような運用を想定しています。

```
├── Project-A
│       └── Vagrantfile
├── Project-B
│       └── Vagrantfile
└── Project-C
        └── Vagrantfile
```

各プロジェクトごとに個別にVMを管理したいのですが、Vagrantfileで同じbox名を指定すると、同じVMが起動してしまいます。

```
config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
```

`bento/ubuntu-16.04`というboxをテンプレートにして個別にVMを管理したいのですが、そういった使い方は可能でしょうか？

Webの情報では1つのVagrantfileから複数のVMを起動するというサンプルしか見つけられませんでした。

**追記**
コメントを受けて、各ツールの情報を開示します。

- プロバイダ VirtualBox 5.1.12
- ホストOS Windows 10
- ゲストOS Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)
- Vagrant 1.9.1

Comment: 利用している config.vm.provider は、virtualbox でしょうか? またホストとなっている OS は何でしょう? また vagrant を含めて、各ツールのバージョンはどうでしょう? それらで回答が変わってきそうな質問内容なので、追記しておくと良い回答が得られる可能性が高まります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vagrantの実装を詳細まで知っている訳ではありませんが、概念的には

1. Virtualboxのイメージ名
2. Vagrantでプロジェクト毎のマシン名の定義(マルチマシン定義)

これらのどちらか（もしくは両方）を変更することでそれぞれ独立したVMとして構築出来ます。

### 1. Virtualboxのイメージ名の変更

Vagrantfileでプロバイダを"virtualbox"に設定しているとのことですので、以下のように変更してみてください。

**Project-AのVagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        # virtualboxの設定
        vb.name="projectA"
    end
end
```

**Project-BのVagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        # virtualboxの設定
        vb.name="projectB"
    end
end
```

このように記述することでVirtualboxのイメージ名を変更することができ、結果としてそれぞれ別のVMとして独立させることが出来ます。

### 2. Vagrantでプロジェクト毎のマシン名の定義(マルチマシン定義)

まず、理解しやすいようにコマンドライン上で

```
vagrant global-status
```

と入力してみてください。すると、これまで作成したVagrant環境一覧が表示されるはずです。
表示されたテーブルに nameという列があると思います。

何も設定していない状態だとここが default になっていると思いますが、これをプロジェクト毎に個別の名前を割り当てることでVMを独立させることが出来ます。

**Project-AのVagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  #マシン名の定義
  config.vm.define "project-a"
end
```

**Project-BのVagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  #マシン名の定義
  config.vm.define "project-b"
end
```

上記を設定後、reloadして再度

```
vagrant global-status
```

で先ほどのテーブルを確認すると、name列にそれぞれ project-a, project-bとしてマシン名が設定出来ているかと思います。